# $T$-odd vs $T$-violation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, time-reversal-symmetry, dipole-moment

I am a bit confused by the difference between $T$-odd and $T$-violation. For example, I read that the existence of a fundamental particle EDM is a violation of time symmetry. However, placing an electric dipole in an electric field, would produce a hamiltonian (non-relativistically, which is usually the region of interest for e.g. atomic experiments): $H = -d\cdot E$, where $d$ is the electric dipole and $E$ is the electric field acting on the (say) electron. The dot product between d and E is odd under time reversal. But I am not sure I understand where the T-violation comes from. I thought that T-odd means just that the system changes sign under T operator, but it is still an eigenstate of it, which means that $T$ and $H$ commute. However, T-violation, I imagined, it means that T and H don't commute. Can someone help me clarify what odd and violation mean in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you blinded yourself to everything about the particle except for the electric dipole moment, then it would indeed look like not much has changed. **However**, fundamental particles have other properties besides an electric dipole moment, such as the spin (an intrinsic magnetic dipole moment).

If *all* properties of a fundamental particle were T-even, or *all* properties of a fundamental particle were T-odd, then time reversal wouldn't do anything, as they would either all stay the same or all flip together. But if one property is T-odd and another is T-even, then *only one* of those properties changes upon time reversal, and therefore a difference can be detected.

For example, the electric dipole moment is T-even and the magnetic dipole moment (the spin) is T-odd. This means that if we start with a particle whose electric and magnetic dipole moments are aligned, and we reverse time, then the spin flips but the electric dipole moment doesn't. Time reversal gives us a particle whose spin and electric dipole moment are *antialigned* rather than aligned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! So in experiments, if you aim to search for an EDM, you would necessary need (continuing with your example) a magnetic field, too. So, basically it is the combined energy shift due to Zeeman effect and Stark (?) effect that changes when running the time backwards, right? If we had just an E-field, the energy splitting would be the same no matter the time direction.

Comment: @BillKet Generally yes, you need some way of measuring both the spin and the electric dipole moment to directly measure T-violation in this way.

Comment: So a particle with spin zero could in principle have an EDM without violating T/CP symmetry?

Comment: @BillKet No, not really. Remember that momentum is T-odd, so if you started out with a spin-0 particle with momentum and EDM aligned, after reversing time you would have a spin-0 particle with momentum and EDM anti-aligned.

Comment: Wait, aren't both momentum and EDM T-odd? Shouldn't they keep the same relative alignment upon time reversal?

Comment: @BillKet Why would the EDM switch directions on time reversal?

Comment: Isn't EDM T-odd?

Comment: @BillKet I don't think so. Think of a classical spinning ball of charge, with a positively-charged north pole and a negatively-charged south pole. Reversing time reverses the direction of the spin, but it doesn't swap the north pole for the south pole, nor does it change positive charge to negative charge.

Comment: I am not sure either. But given that dE is T-odd and E is T-even. Doesn't this imply that d is T-odd? But your argument makes sense, too. Now I am a bit confused.

Comment: Also doesn't EDM come from CP-violating effects of the weak interaction (at least in SM)? Doesn't this mean that EDM is by definition a T-odd moment?

Comment: @BillKet What makes you think that $d\cdot E$ is T-odd?

Comment: Well muB (the magnetic energy) is T-even. If dE would be T-even, too then muB+dE would be T-even, so there will be no T-violation, right?

Comment: @BillKet Energy is T-even, sure (both terms are just energy). That doesn't mean that all properties that you measure about the particle will be T-even.

Comment: Wait i am confused now. T-violation means that [T,H] is not zero. If the hamiltonian is T-even (or T-odd), then [T,H]=0. Don't we need some T-odd and T-even parts at the same time in the energy to have T-violation?

Comment: I found this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.02504.pdf If you look on page 2 second column they mention that dE is T-odd, while E is T-even. Doesn't this imply that d is T-odd? (sorry I might confuse myself but I really want to understand it).

Comment: @BillKet I see; they claim (and this claim is repeated elsewhere) that the electric dipole moment is parallel to the angular momentum vector, which of course is T-odd. I'm posting a separate question about this in particular; in the meantime, I'll be deleting this answer.

Comment: Actually your answer helped! It is the interference between a T-odd and T-even energy term that leads to that violation in principle. I think you reversed the mu and d in terms of even/odd, but your answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

A T-odd operator gains a minus sign when transformed under time reversal. If the Hamiltonian of a system is T-even (this is for example true for an atomic hamiltonian) and you add a T-odd interaction potential to it, the full Hamiltonian will not be an eigenstate of T anymore. Therefore T-invariance is violated.

Writing the EDM interaction as H=-dE makes it indeed not obvious that the EDM is odd under time reversal. But it is. The vector d is necessarily aligned with te spin. This makes it T-odd